# How to insert current CSS media query info to vim statusline?

Tags: css, vim, sass, less

So you have this huge CSS or LESS file. You have multiple same-named rules within different media queries. How do you know what media query is your cursor position currently in? Is it possible to somehow get this information into vim statusline?

Comment: If you provide a sample css text, life will be easier for everyone. People will understand your question better, and the barrier for quick response will be lowered.

Comment: Good point, I'll get a code sample edit in

Comment: @lkraav Did you ever find a workable solution?

Comment: Nothing comprehensive. Pretty sure the folding method is the current best way.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative might be folding. You can set folding to indent and then open/close folds or use fold motions like `[z` and then jump back with tick tick.

```
:set foldmethod=indent
```

then

```
zc
za
```

or

```
[z
``
```

However setting the foldmethod can be tedious. So open/create `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/scss.vim` and add the following line

```
set foldmethod=indent
```

For more help see

```
:h folding
```

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a better way to do this, but you can simply mark your current position and then do the search you need to do

```
"mark current position
mk
"Search for closest @media
?@media<CR>
"go back
`k
```